# Codeigniter Controller name and Object name collision

Tags: php, codeigniter, oop, controller, composer-php

I have encountered a problem and I am not sure how to resolve it.

I have a controller `Pusher` with a method `Auth`

```
class Pusher extends MX_Controller
{
    /**
     *
     */
    public function auth()
    {
        $this->load->model('pusher/Pusher_model');
        $p = $this->Pusher_model->newPusher();
        var_dump($p);die;
    }
}
```

I have a model `Pusher_model` with a method that instantiates a `new Pusher()` object

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

class Pusher_model extends CI_Model
{
    public $options;
    /**
     *
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->config->load('api_config');
        $this->options = array(
            $this->config->item('pusher_cluster'),
            $this->config->item('pusher_is_encrypted')
        );

    }

    /**
     *
     */
    public function newPusher()
    {
        return new Pusher(
            $this->config->item('pusher_public_key'),
            $this->config->item('pusher_secret_key'),
            $this->config->item('pusher_api_id'),
            $this->options
        );
    }
}
```

When I `var_dump()` the returned Pusher object in my controller...

```
var_dump($p)
```

I get the entire controller 'Pusher' as a result...

```
object(Pusher)#24 (2) {
  ["autoload"]=&gt;
  array(0) {
  }
  ["load"]=&gt;
  object(MY_Loader)#25 (13) {
    ["_module":protected]=&gt;
    string(6) "pusher"
    ["_ci_plugins"]=&gt;
    array(0) {
    }
    ["_ci_cached_vars"]=&gt;
    &amp;array(0) {
    }
    ["_ci_ob_level":protected]=&gt;
    int(1)
    ["_ci_view_paths":protected]=&gt;
    &amp;array(1) {
      ["C:\xampp\htdocs\php\twocan\twocan_beta\App\views\"]=&gt;
      bool(true)
    }
    ["_ci_library_paths":protected]=&gt;
    &amp;array(2) {
      [0]=&gt;
      string(43) "C:\xampp\htdocs\php\twocan\twocan_beta\App\"
      [1]=&gt;
      string(43) "C:\xampp\htdocs\php\twocan\twocan_beta\Sys\"
    }
    ["_ci_model_paths":protected]=&gt;
    &amp;array(2) {
      [0]=&gt;
      string(58) "C:\xampp\htdocs\php\twocan\twocan_beta\App\modules/pusher/"
      [1]=&gt;
      string(43) "C:\xampp\htdocs\php\twocan\twocan_beta\App\"
    }
    ["_ci_helper_paths":protected]=&gt;
    &amp;array(2) {
      [0]=&gt;
      string(43) "C:\xampp\htdocs\php\twocan\twocan_beta\App\"
      [1]=&gt;
      string(43) "C:\xampp\htdocs\php\twocan\twocan_beta\Sys\"
    }
    ["_ci_classes":protected]=&gt;
    &amp;array(15) {
      ["benchmark"]=&gt;
      string(9) "Benchmark"
      ["hooks"]=&gt;
      string(5) "Hooks"
      ["config"]=&gt;
      string(6) "Config"
      ["log"]=&gt;
      string(3) "Log"
      ["utf8"]=&gt;
      string(4) "Utf8"
      ["uri"]=&gt;
      string(3) "URI"
      ["router"]=&gt;
      string(6) "Router"
      ["output"]=&gt;
      string(6) "Output"
      ["security"]=&gt;
      string(8) "Security"
      ["input"]=&gt;
      string(5) "Input"
      ["lang"]=&gt;
      string(4) "Lang"
      ["loader"]=&gt;
      string(6) "Loader"
      ["session"]=&gt;
      string(7) "Session"
      ["form_validation"]=&gt;
      string(15) "Form_validation"
      ["model"]=&gt;
      string(5) "Model"
    }
    ["_ci_models":protected]=&gt;
    &amp;array(1) {
      [0]=&gt;
      string(12) "Pusher_model"
    }
    ["_ci_helpers":protected]=&gt;
    &amp;array(5) {
      ["url_helper"]=&gt;
      bool(true)
      ["html_helper"]=&gt;
      bool(true)
      ["security_helper"]=&gt;
      bool(true)
      ["language_helper"]=&gt;
      bool(true)
      ["form_helper"]=&gt;
      bool(true)
    }
    ["_ci_varmap":protected]=&gt;
    &amp;array(2) {
      ["unit_test"]=&gt;
      string(4) "unit"
      ["user_agent"]=&gt;
      string(5) "agent"
    }
    ["controller"]=&gt;
    *RECURSION*
  }
}
```

Which leads me to believe there is a name collision going on with the instantiated object and the controller itself.

**Q:**

How do I resolve this collision without renaming my controller or do I have to use a different controller name to any objects I instantiate through that controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I resolve this collision without renaming my controller or do I have to use a different controller name to any objects I instantiate through that controller?

Ok, let's see..

- the controller is called: `Pusher->auth()`
- the controller loads and calls the model: `$this->Pusher_model->newPusher();`
- then you are instantiating a new Pusher object by using `return new Pusher` and returning it to the `Pusher` controller.
- that means your `Pusher` controller has a property `$p` containing a new pusher object
- yes, you are going in circles here.

---

I would suggest keeping it simple:

- do not instantiate `new Pusher`, but simply return the connection data from the model (`Pusher_model`) to the controller, e.g.

  ```
  public function newPusher()
  {
      return array(
          $this->config->item('pusher_public_key'),
          $this->config->item('pusher_secret_key'),
          $this->config->item('pusher_api_id'),
          $this->options
      );
  }
  ```
- you could also rename the method to `getCredentials` or `getApiConfig`
- that means `$p` is an array and you can work with the data in the controller `Psuher` to set up your API to later make calls to it

---

Another option is to introduce a Service layer between controller and model:

- new class `PusherAPIService`
- instantiated in `controller`
- in controller call `model->getCredentials`
- set/pass credentials to `PusherAPIService`, e.g. `configure($credentials)`
- add actions to `PusherAPIService`, e.g. `connect()`, `pull()`, `push()` whatever your service does. that means that the service class wraps all interaction with the external API.
- then finally in our controller: call the services methods, when you need them. e.g. when a post request comes in, let the controller handle the incoming data, then inject the data into the service layer, then call a method on the now configured service, to get a result back into the controller.

Comment: Wow, nice one Jens, thanks for the tips on architecture, I find that so educational! For the moment I renamed my controller Websockets but your implementation is a good idea.

Comment: Glad i could help :)